# Why Error while running sample in ubuntu of griddb?

Tags: ubuntu, griddb

I have installed griddb in Ubuntu 18.04 running on AWS cloud instance according to given on their website: https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-source-code/#starting-operations
Also in my bin I have all the commands as:

```
# cd bin/
# ls

gs_adduser  gs_joincluster   gs_passwd     gs_stat         gs_stopnode  util.py
gs_deluser  gs_leavecluster  gs_startnode  gs_stopcluster  log.py
```

But when I am starting my cluster I don’t know why it shows error in gs_startnode file as

```
# gs_startnode -u admin/admin -w

ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/griddb/bin/gs_startnode", line 122, in <module>
  proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=f, stderr=f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_childraise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this as I am learning GridDB for some project?